# When to use AxiosResponse with Typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

I have a question about using axis with Typescript. I have a function that does an async call (hitting a free NASA API).

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'; 

interface Camera {
    id: number, 
    name: string, 
    rover_id: number, 
    full_name: string
};

interface Rover {
    id: number, 
    name: string, 
    landing_date: string,
    launch_date: string, 
    status: string, 
}


interface Photo {
    id: number,
    sol: number,
    camera: Camera,
    img_src: string,
    earth_date: string,
    rover: Rover
};

interface Response {
    photo: Photo[]
};


const getData = async (): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    return await axios.get<Response>('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
}
```

Is this correct? If I do this instead

```
const getData = async (): Promise<Response>
```

Typescript gets upset. Is this function not returning a promise that returns the customer `Response` object?

**When should I use AxiosResponse and when should I use my custom interface?**

Comment: AxiosReponse is the return type.of a call of axios.get. Response is the type of object returning in the data field of the AxiosReponse object. So when typing Axios.get<Response> you are saying that the objects in the data field of <AxiosResponse> is typeof Response.

Comment: BTW.to strongly  type the return type of your function,  you can set the return type to Promise<AxiosResponse<Response>> and omit <Response> in the axios.get call.

Answer (score 0):

We have to read the AxiosResponse.data field to get the response data

```
public async getData() : Promise<Response>  {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=DEMO_KEY');
    return response.data; 
}
```